# What are some applied math projects/research Ideas that i could do over the summer

Tags: applications, research

I am a high school senior and before I leave for college I want to learn the process of doing applied mathematics. I am having trouble with coming up with ideas. I know through multivariate/vector calc., linear algebra, some graph theory, and some abstract algebra. I only conditions are it has to be mostly with in my mathematical capabilities, and it cannot be a part of physics.

Comment: Why not get in touch with someone at your college? The undergraduate math director should know who's open to things like this and you'll be building a relationship that will be useful for the next few years.

Comment: You should see if your local community college offers any higher level math classes that you could take over the summer.

Comment: learn a programming language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Potentially try and get into contact with a counselor at the university you plan on attending and see if they have a math club on campus. If they do try and get into contact with them.